# Detecting conflicting snippet trigger keyboard shortcut

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, snippets

Is there a way to detect incompatible snippet triggers?

Say:

```
snippet st "superscript" iA
<---snippet body--->
endsnippet
```

vs

```
snippet bst "binary spanning tree data" iA
<---snippet body--->
endsnippet
```

vs

```
snippet bs "basis information" iA
<---snippet body--->
endsnippet
```

---

Note, `iA` means the snippet will be expanded even in the ***i***nside of a word, ***a***utomatically.

In the above case, `bs` would fire when `bst` is typed, so from the plugin POV there is no conflict, per se.

But from the user POV, `bst` will never fire. Is there a way to possibly call a function in UltiSnips that will detect and report such cases so that the user can choose the snippet triggers correctly without any conflict?

Comment: Perhaps [`:h UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope`](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L430) might be helpful

Comment: @husB Thanks for the suggestion. That link seems to provide a function that I am having trouble understanding.  I have a snippet called `lp` that is supposed to fire with options `bA`. So, in the beginning of the line, I typed `l` (in insert mode), went back to normal mode and then into command mode to issue `:call UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope()` but this gives rise to no noticeable effect. I expected that I get `lp` as a possible trigger word for some snippet. Perhaps I do not understand that documentation correctly.

Comment: I believe your understanding is indeed correct. However, that function returns a dictionary, and doesn't explicitly print anything. Try `:echo UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope()` instead. Also, ensure that the cursor is to the right of `l`.

Comment: Gotcha. What you suggested indeed worked. I had to type `l p` and then delete the space to get `lp` so that the snippet would not fire. Then, when I went into normal mode, the block cursor is on `p` of `lp`. Now issuing the echo command you suggested does indeed give me a list of snippets that start with `l`. So, all of the letters to the *left* of the current cursor position  are taken as argument for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a hackish solution for the problem. It is not an elegant solution. However, since apparently the question keeps getting bumped up to the top for lack of an accepted answer, I will accept my own answer so that everyone can sleep easier. :-)

In case there is an inbuilt solution or a better answer, please do contribute. Thank you.

---

One way to achieve this is the following.

Note that it is the snippets with `A` in their option list cause this problem. So, the following `awk` command processes the `.snippets` file and stores in a separate file the snippet triggers associated with option containing `A`:

```
awk '{if($1 == "snippet" && match($NF, "A"))printf ("%-50s\t%-d\n",$(2),NR)}' tex.snippets > keywords.txt
```

Then, it is a matter of processing these trigger keywords to see which pairs are subsets of each other. That can be accomplished via the following C++ code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
std::vector<std::string> keywords;
std::vector<int> linenumbers;

// Returns -1 if s1 is not a substring of s2
int isSubstring(std::string s1, std::string s2)
{
    int M = s1.length();
    int N = s2.length();
  if (N < M)
    return -1;
    /* A loop to slide pat[] one by one */
    for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) {
        int j;
        /* For current index i, check for
pattern match */
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            if (s2[i + j] != s1[j])
                break;

        if (j == M)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
  std::ifstream ifile("keywords.txt");
  std::ofstream ofile("Processed_output.txt");
  std::string line;
  while (getline(ifile, line)) {
    std::istringstream ss(line);
      int lineno;
    while (!ss.eof()) {
      std::string hname;
      ss >> hname; 
      if (hname.length() > 0) {
        keywords.push_back(hname);
        ss >> lineno;
        linenumbers.push_back(lineno);
      }
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < keywords.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < keywords.size(); j++) {
      if (i == j)
        continue;
      if (isSubstring(keywords[i], keywords[j]) == -1) {
      }
      else {
        printf("Clash between %s [%d] and %s [%d]\n", keywords[i].c_str(), linenumbers[i], keywords[j].c_str(), linenumbers[j]);
        ofile << "Clash between " << keywords[i] << " ["<<linenumbers[i]<<"] and " << keywords[j] << " ["<<linenumbers[j]<<"]"<<std::endl; 
      }
    }
  }
  ifile.close();
  ofile.close();
}
```

This shows all the "clashes" for further analysis/correction.

Comment: Maybe you should accept your solution for clarity and to stop popping up for confirmation?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt What? I haven't been in thread in a long time. What precisely is the issue that seems to irk you?

Comment: Nothing important :-) It seems you have the solution to your problem. Maybe could you validate (accept via the green v) your solution.

Comment: I see. I usually do not have a practice to accept my own answers -- the present one seems hackish and I was hoping there is a better solution out there.  I was under the impression that you were asking me to accept the answer because for some reason this question is "popping up for confirmation" ? I do not know what this means or why this happens? If no answer is accepted, is it a problem?

Comment: Feel free to do what is best for you :-)

Comment: The question gets bumped to the top of the homepage every so often when it has no « good » answers (either upvoted or accepted). I’ll upvote, I guess, though I’d prefer some non-CPP code for post-processing, personally.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Accepted so that everyone can sleep better :-)